# How to cat /dev/ttyUSB0 to new file daily

Tags: scripting, cat, logs

I have a script that simply does this:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > /home/pi/usb0_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).txt
```

It runs great, but I want to create a new file each day instead of one big file.

I thought about using crontab to do this, but I don't know how to get the first day's job to end before starting the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [`timeout` utility in GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) for exactly that, run:

```
timeout 86400 cat ... > ...
```

Comment: For those lacking GNUs, a script `cat … > … & sleep 86400; kill %1` should be similar

Comment: The question originally mentioned Linux in passing, and `/dev/ttyUSB0` sounds like linux, so I assumed a GNU userspace. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to skip the needless complication of killing daily and instead pipe the output to e.g. [rotatelog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) or [cronolog](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cronolog) that would then daily rotate the output to a new file.

```
... | ...rotatelogs -l /home/pi/usb0_%Y%m%d 86400
```